# Outlook 2007 HTML Setting table width

Tags: html, outlook, outlook-2007

I'm attempting to set a table width in a newsletter I am generating using HTML. I understand that CSS can't be used with Outlook and that styling basically needs to be included with content.

What I'm really struggling with is trying to set a set width for the table. Right now it is too wide and I'd like to trim it down. I'd like to move the width to the green line instead of the red line.

[image]

I've tried playing with the following code but no luck..

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You've probably got another row or element somewhere with a larger width than 150px that is overriding what you've got. I'd be happy to help you out if you post more of your HTML. I used to create a lot of HTML emails so I've had this happen in the past, and it's usually something you're not noticing that is overriding what you want.

Comment: Hi there welcome to SO, this should rather be left as a comment